# Sort lines by html attribute in vim

Tags: sorting, vim

I have a bunch of lines in a row that look like `<a href="url" alt="name">text</a>` and I want to reorder them into alphabetical order, using the `alt` attribute to sort. Is there a slick one or two lines of vimscript that I could use to get this? For concreteness, there are no line breaks in any of the entries and the relevant lines are 17-35.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression as argument to the built-in `:sort` command:

```
:17,35sort /.*alt="\zs/
```

Comment: Where the text matched by pattern is skipped.